# Initialize Observable Collection using Anonymous Method

Tags: c#, wpf

Just trying to do something basic and am getting stuck. Want to initialize an observable collection in my model class (See code below) and cant seem to get it working. I have put in **_** for the part which is not working.

Can somebody please provide pointers

```
public class StockModel : ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, TickerDetails>>
{
    #region Properties
    public string TickerSymbol { get; set; }
    public TickerDetails Ticker { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public StockModel()
    {
        init();   
    }

    public void init()
    {
        Add(new KeyValuePair<string, TickerDetails> { "ABC", new TickerDetails {TickerName="ABC", LastPrice=30, Ask=40, Bid=50, Volume=60 }});
    }

    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, TickerDetails>> getData()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

public class TickerDetails
{
    public string TickerName { get; set; }
    public int LastPrice { get; set; }
    public int Bid { get; set; }
    public int Ask { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can do the traditional way (like below) but want to learn the above methodology

```
Dictionary<int, StudentName> students = new Dictionary<int, StudentName>()
{
    { 111, new StudentName {FirstName="Sachin", LastName="Karnik", ID=211}},
    { 112, new StudentName {FirstName="Dina", LastName="Salimzianova", ID=317}},
    { 113, new StudentName {FirstName="Andy", LastName="Ruth", ID=198}}
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you want StockModel to actually inherit ObservableCollection? Its unclear what you want StockModel to be since it has a single string as the Ticker, and a single set of details, yet is a collection...

Comment: One oddity, in your Add() method, you are adding a different type to the ObservableCollection.  The collection has KVP<string, List<int>> and you are adding a KVP<string, TickerDetails>.

Comment: Yes - The reason I am building it this way is because this is the model - which will then be injected into ViewModel and further displayed into the view. This is the mini version of StockModel - still need to add more properties for Diff charting controls all which will be based on this StockModel

Comment: Steve -Sorry just updated that error - initially I was trying to do this with a List<int> but later changed to a object since it made more logical sense for my purpose. Have updated the code.

Comment: just a suggestion, i'd make more sense of this if you had posted compilable code with notations as comments...

Comment: Sorry everybody - Since I had posted the mis-mash version of the code. Have now updated to the correct one and am still getting this error - Cannot initialize type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,TickerDetails> with a collection initializer because it does not implement System.Collections.IEnumerable

Comment: That makes sense, change the {} after your KVP<string,TickerDetails> to ()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the type on your inherited ObservableCollection:

```
ObservableCollection<string, List<int>>
```

This makes your type a collection of strings and lists, not strings and TickerDetails. Change your inherited type to string, TickerDetails and you'll be able to initialize. However you'll also need to change the signiture of getData() to match the new inherited signiture, or provide a transformation from TickerDetails to List, Int

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that

```
Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object> { "ABC", new TickerDetails { TickerName = "tick tock", LastPrice = 10 }});
```

?

You just have to instantiate a new TickerDetails as well.

Anyway, that doesn't match an `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>>` so it's more like:

```
Add(new KeyValuePair<string, List<int>> { "ABC", new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }});
```

EDIT: with your latest edit, the first example should work.

Comment: Or perhaps `Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("ABC", new TickerDetails { TickerName = "tick tock", LastPrice = 10 }));` since the element type is `KVP<string, object>` and KVP has a constructor with key and value argument.

Comment: Sorry everybody since I had posted the mis-mash version of the code. Have now updated to the correct one and am still getting this error - Cannot initialize type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,TickerDetails> with a collection initializer because it does not implement System.Collections.IEnumerable